# How to rsync between two server via their common windows host

Tags: rsync, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

We are migrating 100s of gigs of data from in house server to external server. We tried a lot but still those two servers can't talk to each other, probably due to corporate security. The current setup is like this:

```
                  |-----> CentOS (T) [Target]
Win10 (A)  ------>|
                  |-----> Ubuntu Jumpbox (U) ----> Ubuntu (S) [Source]
```

S cannot talk to T directly.

I am trying to move data via tunnel through Win10 jumpbox which can access both servers.
`S--> U --> A ---> T`

Is there anyway this can be done? Can we reverse tunnel to Windows host from linux? My backup plan it to just sftp files on A and upload them to T which will just double the downtime during file migrations.

---

**Edit:** Backup plan failed short of expectation. Linux filenames having special characters and case senstive duplicate file names are not transferring to windows.

Comment: The most sane solution would be to get a Change Request through the process that allows SSH (and hence `rsync`) from your internal system to the external one.

Comment: Installing a small linux distro alongside win10 is another way to do it, but I second @roaima, ask for the restrictions to be removed

Comment: Linux distro is an option. I am trying reverse tunnel with plink/putty, but no success so far.

Comment: There is a program called [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) which also runs on windows (using openssl). This can act as tunnel client and server; combining both in your windows machine might be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if correct scp version is available in MinGW but you can use -3 option :

> man scp
>
> [...]
>
> -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between
>   the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the
>                 progress meter.
>
> [...]